# C# Color implementation with conversions from RGB to HSL and CMYK and vice versa, targetting Blazor and CSS

Tags: c#, css, color, blazor

This is an implementation of a Color class, primarily targetting the web to be used in a Blazor app.

**Color.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Color
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a Color with Red, Green, Blue and Alpha channels, packed into an integer. Also contains utilities to convert between color spaces.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// Since the colors are stored in ARGB, if you create a Color from other color spaces you might lose precision.
    /// This means that converting back and forth between color spaces does not guarantee you getting the original value.
    /// All percentage values are within [0.0, 1.0] and the smallest possible delta is 1 / 255. So an alpha of 0.001 and 0.002 are the same.
    /// Static constructors take tuples and constructors take each value separately.
    /// 
    /// Currently supported color spaces conversion: RGB, HSL, CMYK.
    public struct Color : IEquatable<Color>, ICloneable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents ARGB as a densely packed integer.
        /// </summary>
        public uint Value { get; private set; }

        #region Checks

        private static bool NotInPctRange(double v)
        {
            return v < 0.0 || v > 1.0;
        }

        private static bool NotInByteRange(uint v)
        {
            return v > 255;
        }

        private static bool NotInRgbRange(double r, double g, double b)
        {
            return NotInPctRange(r) || NotInPctRange(g) || NotInPctRange(b);
        }

        private static bool NotInRgbRange(uint r, uint g, uint b)
        {
            return NotInByteRange(r) || NotInByteRange(g) || NotInByteRange(b);
        }

        private static bool NotInHslRange(double h, double s, double v)
        {
            return h < 0.0 || h > 359.0 ||  NotInPctRange(s) || NotInPctRange(v);
        }

        private static bool NotInCmykRange(double c, double m, double y, double k)
        {
            return NotInPctRange(c) || NotInPctRange(m) || NotInPctRange(y) || NotInPctRange(k);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Getters

        /// <summary>
        /// The value of Alpha within [0, 255]
        /// </summary>
        public uint A => Value >> 24;

        /// <summary>
        /// The value of Red within [0, 255]
        /// </summary>
        public uint R => (Value >> 16) & 0xFF;

        /// <summary>
        /// The value of Green within [0, 255]
        /// </summary>
        public uint G => (Value >> 8) & 0xFF;

        /// <summary>
        /// The value of Blue within [0, 255]
        /// </summary>
        public uint B => Value & 0xFF;

        /// <summary>
        /// Masks off the Alpha value, returning only RGB
        /// </summary>
        public uint RGB => Value & 0xFFFFFF;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Alpha within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Alpha => A / 255.0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Red within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Red => R / 255.0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Green within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Green => G / 255.0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Blue within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Blue => B / 255.0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Hue within [0.0, 359.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Hue
        {
            get {
                var r = Red;
                var g = Green;
                var b = Blue;

                var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);
                var min = Math.Min(Math.Min(r, g), b);
                var c = max - min;

                if (c != 0)
                {
                    if (max == r)
                    {
                        var segment = (g - b) / c;
                        var shift = 0 / 60;
                        if (segment < 0)
                            shift = 360 / 60;
                        return (segment + shift) * 60;
                    }
                    else if (max == g)
                    {
                        var segment = (b - r) / c;
                        var shift = 120 / 60;
                        return (segment + shift) * 60;
                    }
                    else if (max == b)
                    {
                        var segment = (r - g) / c;
                        var shift = 240 / 60;
                        return (segment + shift) * 60;
                    }
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Saturation within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Saturation
        {
            get
            {
                var r = Red;
                var g = Green;
                var b = Blue;

                var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);
                var min = Math.Min(Math.Min(r, g), b);

                var l = (max + min) / 2; // Lightness

                if (min != max)
                {
                    if (l < 0.5)
                        return (max - min) / (max + min);

                    return (max - min) / (2 - max - min);
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Lightness within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Lightness
        {
            get
            {
                var r = Red;
                var g = Green;
                var b = Blue;

                var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);
                var min = Math.Min(Math.Min(r, g), b);

                return (max + min) / 2;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Cyan within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Cyan
        {
            get
            {
                var k = Black;
                return k == 1.0 ? 0.0 : (1.0 - Red - k) / (1.0 - k);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Magenta within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Magenta
        {
            get
            {
                var k = Black;
                return k == 1.0 ? 0.0 : (1.0 - Green - k) / (1.0 - k);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Yellow within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Yellow
        {
            get
            {
                var k = Black;
                return k == 1.0 ? 0.0 : (1.0 - Blue - k) / (1.0 - k);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns value of Black within [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        public double Black => 1.0 - Math.Max(Math.Max(Red, Green), Blue);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the relative Luminance (how bright to the human eye the color is) according to ITU BT.601.
        /// </summary>
        public double Luminance => (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B) / 255.0;

        #endregion

        #region Value Tuples

        /// <summary>
        /// A tuple with RGB values as integers within [0, 255].
        /// </summary>
        public (uint, uint, uint)RGBValuesInt()
        {
            return (R, G, B);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A tuple with RGB values within [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        public (double, double, double)RGBValues()
        {
            return (Red, Green, Blue);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A tuple with HSL values within [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        public (double, double, double)HSLValues()
        {
            return RgbToHslInt((R, G, B));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A tuple with CMYK values within [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        public (double, double, double, double)CMYKValues()
        {
            return RgbToCmykInt((R, G, B));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ctors

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Color from an integer value.
        /// </summary>
        public Color(uint value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from a hexadecimal string, converting it to an integer and assigning to Value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hexa">A string as a hexadecimal number</param>
        public Color(string hexa)
        {
            Value = Convert.ToUInt32(hexa, 16);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green and Blue channels with 100% Alpha, ranging from [0, 255].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="r">Red value</param>
        /// <param name="g">Green value</param>
        /// <param name="b">Blue value</param>
        public Color(uint r, uint g, uint b)
        {
            if (NotInRgbRange(r, g, b))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("", $"R, G, B and A need to be within [0, 255]. Instead got r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}");

            Value = ((uint)0xFF << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green, Blue and Alpha channels, ranging from [0, 255].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="r">Red value</param>
        /// <param name="g">Green value</param>
        /// <param name="b">Blue value</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        public Color(uint r, uint g, uint b, uint a)
        {
            if (NotInRgbRange(r, g, b) || a > 255)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("", $"R, G, B and A need to be within [0, 255]. Instead got r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}, a: {a}");

            Value = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green, Blue and Alpha channels, with RGB ranging from [0, 255], and Alpha, from [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="r">Red value</param>
        /// <param name="g">Green value</param>
        /// <param name="b">Blue value</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        public Color(uint r, uint g, uint b, double a)
        {
            if (NotInRgbRange(r, g, b) || a > 1.0 || a < 0.0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("", $"R, G, B need to be within [0, 255] and A within [0.0, 1.0]. Instead got r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}, a: {a}");

            var a_ = (uint)Math.Round(a * 255.0, 0);
            Value = (a_ << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green and Blue channels with 100% Alpha, ranging from [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="r">Red value</param>
        /// <param name="g">Green value</param>
        /// <param name="b">Blue value</param>
        public Color(double r, double g, double b)
        {
            if (NotInRgbRange(r, g, b))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("", $"R, G and B need to be within [0.0, 1.0]. Instead got r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}");

            var (r_, g_, b_) = PctToRgb(r, g, b);
            Value = ((uint)0xFF << 24) | (r_ << 16) | (g_ << 8) | b_;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green, Blue and Alpha channels, ranging from [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="r">Red value</param>
        /// <param name="g">Green value</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        public Color(double r, double g, double b, double a)
        {
            if (NotInRgbRange(r, g, b) || a > 1.0 || a < 0.0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("", $"R, G, B and A need to be within [0.0, 1.0]. Instead got r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}, a: {a}");

            var (r_, g_, b_) = PctToRgb(r, g, b);
            var a_ = (uint)Math.Round(a * 255.0, 0);
            Value = (a_ << 24) | (r_ << 16) | (g_ << 8) | b_;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Static Ctors

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from a string, converting it to an integer and assigning to Value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hexa">A string as a hexadecimal number</param>
        public static Color FromHexa(string hexa)
        {
            return new Color(hexa);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green, Blue and Alpha channels. All numbers ranging from 0 to 255.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (R, G, B)</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        public static Color FromRGBA((uint, uint, uint) rgb, uint a)
        {
            var (r, g, b) = rgb;
            return new Color(r, g, b, a);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green, Blue and Alpha channels. RGB ranging from 0 to 255, and Alpha, from 0.0 to 1.0.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (R, G, B)</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        public static Color FromRGBA((uint, uint, uint) rgb, double a)
        {
            var (r, g, b) = rgb;
            return new Color(r, g, b, a);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green, Blue and Alpha components. All numbers ranging from 0.0 to 1.0.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (R, G, B)</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        public static Color FromRGBA((double, double, double) rgb, double a)
        {
            var (r, g, b) = rgb;
            return new Color(r, g, b, a);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green and Blue channels with 100% Alpha and values within [0, 255].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (R, G, B)</param>
        public static Color FromRGB((uint, uint, uint) rgb)
        {
            return FromRGBA(rgb, 255);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Red, Green and Blue channels with 100% Alpha and values within [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (R, G, B)</param>
        public static Color FromRGB((double, double, double) rgb)
        {
            return FromRGBA(rgb, 1.0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Hue, Saturation and Value, with Hue within [0.0, 359.0], and the others, within [0.0, 1.0]. Alpha is at 100%.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hsl">A tuple of form (H, S, L)</param>
        public static Color FromHSL((double, double, double) hsl)
        {
            return FromRGBA(HslToRgb(hsl), 1.0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Hue, Saturation, Value, and Alpha, with Hue within [0.0, 359.0], and the others, within [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hsl">A tuple of form (H, S, L)</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        public static Color FromHSLA((double, double, double) hsl, double a)
        {
            return FromRGBA(HslToRgb(hsl), a);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Black, with values within [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hsl">A tuple of form (C, M, Y, K)</param>
        public static Color FromCMYK((double, double, double, double) cmyk)
        {
            return FromRGBA(CmykToRgb(cmyk), 1.0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Color from Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black and Alpha, with values within [0.0, 1.0].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hsl">A tuple of form (C, M, Y, K)</param>
        /// <param name="a">Alpha value</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Color FromCMYKA((double, double, double, double) cmyk, double a)
        {
            return FromRGBA(CmykToRgb(cmyk), a);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Conversions

        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms RGB color space to HSL.
        /// </summary>
        ///
        /// RGB values must be in range [0.0, 1.0].
        ///
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form Tuple of form (Hue, Saturation, Lightness)</returns>
        public static (double, double, double) RgbToHsl((double, double, double) rgb)
        {
            double hue = 0.0, sat = 0.0, light;

            (double r, double g, double b) = rgb;

            if (NotInRgbRange(r, g, b))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rbg", $"R, G and B must be in range [0.0, 1.0]. Instead got r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}");

            var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);
            var min = Math.Min(Math.Min(r, g), b);

            var c = max - min;

            if (c != 0)
            {
                if (max == r)
                {
                    var segment = (g - b) / c;
                    var shift = 0 / 60;
                    if (segment < 0)
                        shift = 360 / 60;
                    hue = (segment + shift) * 60;
                }
                else if (max == g)
                {
                    var segment = (b - r) / c;
                    var shift = 120 / 60;
                    hue =  (segment + shift) * 60;
                }
                else if (max == b)
                {
                    var segment = (r - g) / c;
                    var shift = 240 / 60;
                    hue = (segment + shift) * 60;
                }
            }

            light = (max + min) / 2;

            if (min != max)
            {
                if (light < 0.5)
                    sat = (max - min) / (max + min);
                else
                    sat = (max - min) / (2 - max - min);
            }

            return (hue, sat, light);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms RGB color space to HSL.
        /// </summary>
        ///
        /// RGB values must be in range [0, 255].
        ///
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form (Hue, Saturation, Lightness) within [0.0, 1.0]</returns>
        public static (double, double, double) RgbToHslInt((uint, uint, uint) rgb)
        {
            (uint r_, uint g_, uint b_) = rgb;

            if (NotInRgbRange(r_, g_, b_))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rbg", $"R, G and B must be in range [0, 255]. Instead got r: {r_}, g: {g_}, b: {b_}");

            (double r, double g, double b) = RgbToPct(r_, g_, b_);

            return RgbToHsl((r, g, b));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms RGB color space to CMYK.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// RGB values must be in range [0.0, 1.0].
        /// 
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black) within [0.0, 1.0]</returns>
        public static (double, double, double, double) RgbToCmyk((double, double, double) rgb)
        {
            double c, m, y, k;

            (double r, double g, double b) = rgb;

            if (NotInRgbRange(r, g, b))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rbg", $"R, G and B must be in range [0.0, 1.0]. Instead got r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}");

            var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);

            k = 1 - max;

            if (k == 1)
            {
                c = m = y = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                c = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k);
                m = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k);
                y = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k);
            }

            return (c, m, y, k);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms RGB color space to CMYK.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// RGB values must be in range [0, 255].
        /// 
        /// <param name="rgb">A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black) within [0.0, 1.0]</returns>
        public static (double, double, double, double) RgbToCmykInt((uint, uint, uint) rgb)
        {
            (uint r_, uint g_, uint b_) = rgb;

            if (NotInRgbRange(r_, g_, b_))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rbg", $"R, G and B must be in range [0, 255]. Instead got r: {r_}, g: {g_}, b: {b_}");

            (double r, double g, double b) = RgbToPct(r_, g_, b_);

            return RgbToCmyk((r, g, b));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms HSL color space to RGB.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// H value must be in range [0.0, 359.0] and SL values must be in range [0.0, 1.0].
        /// 
        /// <param name="hsl">A tuple of form (Hue, Saturation, Lightness)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue) within [0.0, 1.0]</returns>
        public static (double, double, double) HslToRgb((double, double, double) hsl)
        {
            (double hue, double sat, double light) = hsl;

            if (NotInHslRange(hue, sat, light))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("hsl", $"H must be in range [0.0, 359.0], and S and L must be in range [0.0, 1.0]. Instead got h: {hue}, s: {sat}, l: {light}");

            hue /= 60;

            double t2;
            if (light <= 0.5)
            {
                t2 = light * (sat + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                t2 = light + sat - (light * sat);
            }

            double t1 = light * 2 - t2;

            return (HueToRgb(t1, t2, hue + 2.0), HueToRgb(t1, t2, hue), HueToRgb(t1, t2, hue - 2));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms HSL color space to RGB.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// H value must be in range [0.0, 359.0] and SL values must be in range [0.0, 1.0].
        /// 
        /// <param name="hsl">A tuple of form (Hue, Saturation, Lightness)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue)</returns>
        public static (uint, uint, uint) HslToRgbInt((double, double, double) hsl)
        {
            var (r, g, b) = HslToRgb(hsl);
            return PctToRgb(r, g, b);
        }

        public static double HueToRgb(double t1, double t2, double hue)
        {
            if (hue < 0.0)
                hue += 6.0;
            if (hue >= 6.0)
                hue -= 6.0;

            if (hue < 1.0)
                return (t2 - t1) * hue + t1;
            else if (hue < 3.0)
                return t2;
            else if (hue < 4.0)
                return (t2 - t1) * (4.0 - hue) + t1;

            return t1;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms CMYK color space to RGB.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// CMYK values must be in range [0.0, 1.0].
        /// 
        /// <param name="cmyk">A tuple of form (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue) within [0.0, 1.0]</returns>
        public static (double, double, double) CmykToRgb((double c, double m, double y, double k) cmyk)
        {
            var (c, m, y, k) = cmyk;

            if (NotInCmykRange(c, m, y, k))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("cmyk", $"CMYK must be in range [0.0, 1.0]. Instead got c: {c}, m: {m}, y: {y}, k: {k}");

            var r = 1 - (Math.Min(1, c * (1 - k) + k));
            var g = 1 - (Math.Min(1, m * (1 - k) + k));
            var b = 1 - (Math.Min(1, y * (1 - k) + k));

            return (r, g, b);
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms CMYK color space to RGB.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// CMYK values must be in range [0.0, 1.0].
        /// 
        /// <param name="cmyk">A tuple of form (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black)</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of form (Red, Green, Blue)</returns>
        public static (uint, uint, uint) CmykToRgbInt((double c, double m, double y, double k) cmyk)
        {
            var (r, g, b) = CmykToRgb(cmyk);
            return PctToRgb(r, g, b);
        }

        #endregion

        #region ToCSS

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Color to fit into an rgba CSS function, with form rbga(R, G, B, A).
        /// </summary>
        public string ToCssRgba()
        {
            return $"rgba({R}, {G}, {B}, {DefaultFormat(A / 255.0)})";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Color to fit into an hsla CSS function, with form hsl(H, S%, L%, A)
        /// </summary>
        public string ToCssHsla()
        {
            var (h, s, l) = RgbToHsl((Red, Green, Blue));
            return $"hsla({DefaultFormat(h)}, {DefaultFormat(s * 100)}%, {DefaultFormat(l * 100)}%, {DefaultFormat(A / 255.0)})";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Color with a format of #RRGGBB.
        /// </summary>
        public string ToCssColor()
        {
            return $"#{Convert.ToString(RGB, 16).PadLeft(6, '0')}";
        }

        #endregion

        #region Misc

        /// <summary>
        /// [0, 255] -> [0.0, 1.0]
        /// </summary>
        private static (double, double, double) RgbToPct(uint r, uint g, uint b)
        {
            return (r / 255.0, g / 255.0, b / 255.0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [0.0, 1.0] -> [0, 255]
        /// </summary>
        private static (uint, uint, uint) PctToRgb(double r, double g, double b)
        {
            return ((uint)Math.Round(r * 255.0, 0), (uint)Math.Round(g * 255.0, 0), (uint)Math.Round(b * 255.0, 0));
        }

        private static string DefaultFormat(double value)
        {
            return value.ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Overrides + Impls

        public static bool operator ==(Color lhs, Color rhs)
        {
            return lhs.Value == rhs.Value;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Color lhs, Color rhs)
        {
            return lhs.Value != rhs.Value;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Color c)
                return Value == c.Value;

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value.ToString("X");
        }

        public bool Equals(Color other)
        {
            return Value == other.Value;
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return new Color(Value);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is an example of using it on a console application:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var color1 = new Color(49, 100, 200);
        var color2 = Color.FromHSL(color1.HSLValues());

        if (color1 == color2)
            Console.WriteLine("yay!");
        
        var color3 = new Color(color2.ToString());

        if (color1 == color3 && color2 == color3 && color3 == color3)
            Console.WriteLine("yay!");

        Console.WriteLine(color1);
        Console.WriteLine(color2);
        Console.WriteLine(color3);
    }
}
```

I've taken all the named colors from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp) and added to a separate static class that can be very usefull:

**Colors.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Color
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp
    /// </summary>
    public static class Colors
    {
        public static Color AliceBlue => new Color(0xFFF0F8FF);
        public static Color AntiqueWhite => new Color(0xFFFAEBD7);
        public static Color Aqua => new Color(0xFF00FFFF);
        public static Color Aquamarine => new Color(0xFF7FFFD4);
        public static Color Azure => new Color(0xFFF0FFFF);
        public static Color Beige => new Color(0xFFF5F5DC);
        public static Color Bisque => new Color(0xFFFFE4C4);
        public static Color Black => new Color(0xFF000000);
        public static Color BlanchedAlmond => new Color(0xFFFFEBCD);
        public static Color Blue => new Color(0xFF0000FF);
        public static Color BlueViolet => new Color(0xFF8A2BE2);
        public static Color Brown => new Color(0xFFA52A2A);
        public static Color BurlyWood => new Color(0xFFDEB887);
        public static Color CadetBlue => new Color(0xFF5F9EA0);
        public static Color Chartreuse => new Color(0xFF7FFF00);
        public static Color Chocolate => new Color(0xFFD2691E);
        public static Color Coral => new Color(0xFFFF7F50);
        public static Color CornflowerBlue => new Color(0xFF6495ED);
        public static Color Cornsilk => new Color(0xFFFFF8DC);
        public static Color Crimson => new Color(0xFFDC143C);
        public static Color Cyan => new Color(0xFF00FFFF);
        public static Color DarkBlue => new Color(0xFF00008B);
        public static Color DarkCyan => new Color(0xFF008B8B);
        public static Color DarkGoldenRod => new Color(0xFFB8860B);
        public static Color DarkGray => new Color(0xFFA9A9A9);
        public static Color DarkGrey => new Color(0xFFA9A9A9);
        public static Color DarkGreen => new Color(0xFF006400);
        public static Color DarkKhaki => new Color(0xFFBDB76B);
        public static Color DarkMagenta => new Color(0xFF8B008B);
        public static Color DarkOliveGreen => new Color(0xFF556B2F);
        public static Color DarkOrange => new Color(0xFFFF8C00);
        public static Color DarkOrchid => new Color(0xFF9932CC);
        public static Color DarkRed => new Color(0xFF8B0000);
        public static Color DarkSalmon => new Color(0xFFE9967A);
        public static Color DarkSeaGreen => new Color(0xFF8FBC8F);
        public static Color DarkSlateBlue => new Color(0xFF483D8B);
        public static Color DarkSlateGray => new Color(0xFF2F4F4F);
        public static Color DarkSlateGrey => new Color(0xFF2F4F4F);
        public static Color DarkTurquoise => new Color(0xFF00CED1);
        public static Color DarkViolet => new Color(0xFF9400D3);
        public static Color DeepPink => new Color(0xFFFF1493);
        public static Color DeepSkyBlue => new Color(0xFF00BFFF);
        public static Color DimGray => new Color(0xFF696969);
        public static Color DimGrey => new Color(0xFF696969);
        public static Color DodgerBlue => new Color(0xFF1E90FF);
        public static Color FireBrick => new Color(0xFFB22222);
        public static Color FloralWhite => new Color(0xFFFFFAF0);
        public static Color ForestGreen => new Color(0xFF228B22);
        public static Color Fuchsia => new Color(0xFFFF00FF);
        public static Color Gainsboro => new Color(0xFFDCDCDC);
        public static Color GhostWhite => new Color(0xFFF8F8FF);
        public static Color Gold => new Color(0xFFFFD700);
        public static Color GoldenRod => new Color(0xFFDAA520);
        public static Color Gray => new Color(0xFF808080);
        public static Color Grey => new Color(0xFF808080);
        public static Color Green => new Color(0xFF008000);
        public static Color GreenYellow => new Color(0xFFADFF2F);
        public static Color HoneyDew => new Color(0xFFF0FFF0);
        public static Color HotPink => new Color(0xFFFF69B4);
        public static Color IndianRed => new Color(0xFFCD5C5C);
        public static Color Indigo => new Color(0xFF4B0082);
        public static Color Ivory => new Color(0xFFFFFFF0);
        public static Color Khaki => new Color(0xFFF0E68C);
        public static Color Lavender => new Color(0xFFE6E6FA);
        public static Color LavenderBlush => new Color(0xFFFFF0F5);
        public static Color LawnGreen => new Color(0xFF7CFC00);
        public static Color LemonChiffon => new Color(0xFFFFFACD);
        public static Color LightBlue => new Color(0xFFADD8E6);
        public static Color LightCoral => new Color(0xFFF08080);
        public static Color LightCyan => new Color(0xFFE0FFFF);
        public static Color LightGoldenRodYellow => new Color(0xFFFAFAD2);
        public static Color LightGray => new Color(0xFFD3D3D3);
        public static Color LightGrey => new Color(0xFFD3D3D3);
        public static Color LightGreen => new Color(0xFF90EE90);
        public static Color LightPink => new Color(0xFFFFB6C1);
        public static Color LightSalmon => new Color(0xFFFFA07A);
        public static Color LightSeaGreen => new Color(0xFF20B2AA);
        public static Color LightSkyBlue => new Color(0xFF87CEFA);
        public static Color LightSlateGray => new Color(0xFF778899);
        public static Color LightSlateGrey => new Color(0xFF778899);
        public static Color LightSteelBlue => new Color(0xFFB0C4DE);
        public static Color LightYellow => new Color(0xFFFFFFE0);
        public static Color Lime => new Color(0xFF00FF00);
        public static Color LimeGreen => new Color(0xFF32CD32);
        public static Color Linen => new Color(0xFFFAF0E6);
        public static Color Magenta => new Color(0xFFFF00FF);
        public static Color Maroon => new Color(0xFF800000);
        public static Color MediumAquaMarine => new Color(0xFF66CDAA);
        public static Color MediumBlue => new Color(0xFF0000CD);
        public static Color MediumOrchid => new Color(0xFFBA55D3);
        public static Color MediumPurple => new Color(0xFF9370DB);
        public static Color MediumSeaGreen => new Color(0xFF3CB371);
        public static Color MediumSlateBlue => new Color(0xFF7B68EE);
        public static Color MediumSpringGreen => new Color(0xFF00FA9A);
        public static Color MediumTurquoise => new Color(0xFF48D1CC);
        public static Color MediumVioletRed => new Color(0xFFC71585);
        public static Color MidnightBlue => new Color(0xFF191970);
        public static Color MintCream => new Color(0xFFF5FFFA);
        public static Color MistyRose => new Color(0xFFFFE4E1);
        public static Color Moccasin => new Color(0xFFFFE4B5);
        public static Color NavajoWhite => new Color(0xFFFFDEAD);
        public static Color Navy => new Color(0xFF000080);
        public static Color OldLace => new Color(0xFFFDF5E6);
        public static Color Olive => new Color(0xFF808000);
        public static Color OliveDrab => new Color(0xFF6B8E23);
        public static Color Orange => new Color(0xFFFFA500);
        public static Color OrangeRed => new Color(0xFFFF4500);
        public static Color Orchid => new Color(0xFFDA70D6);
        public static Color PaleGoldenRod => new Color(0xFFEEE8AA);
        public static Color PaleGreen => new Color(0xFF98FB98);
        public static Color PaleTurquoise => new Color(0xFFAFEEEE);
        public static Color PaleVioletRed => new Color(0xFFDB7093);
        public static Color PapayaWhip => new Color(0xFFFFEFD5);
        public static Color PeachPuff => new Color(0xFFFFDAB9);
        public static Color Peru => new Color(0xFFCD853F);
        public static Color Pink => new Color(0xFFFFC0CB);
        public static Color Plum => new Color(0xFFDDA0DD);
        public static Color PowderBlue => new Color(0xFFB0E0E6);
        public static Color Purple => new Color(0xFF800080);
        public static Color RebeccaPurple => new Color(0xFF663399);
        public static Color Red => new Color(0xFFFF0000);
        public static Color RosyBrown => new Color(0xFFBC8F8F);
        public static Color RoyalBlue => new Color(0xFF4169E1);
        public static Color SaddleBrown => new Color(0xFF8B4513);
        public static Color Salmon => new Color(0xFFFA8072);
        public static Color SandyBrown => new Color(0xFFF4A460);
        public static Color SeaGreen => new Color(0xFF2E8B57);
        public static Color SeaShell => new Color(0xFFFFF5EE);
        public static Color Sienna => new Color(0xFFA0522D);
        public static Color Silver => new Color(0xFFC0C0C0);
        public static Color SkyBlue => new Color(0xFF87CEEB);
        public static Color SlateBlue => new Color(0xFF6A5ACD);
        public static Color SlateGray => new Color(0xFF708090);
        public static Color SlateGrey => new Color(0xFF708090);
        public static Color Snow => new Color(0xFFFFFAFA);
        public static Color SpringGreen => new Color(0xFF00FF7F);
        public static Color SteelBlue => new Color(0xFF4682B4);
        public static Color Tan => new Color(0xFFD2B48C);
        public static Color Teal => new Color(0xFF008080);
        public static Color Thistle => new Color(0xFFD8BFD8);
        public static Color Tomato => new Color(0xFFFF6347);
        public static Color Turquoise => new Color(0xFF40E0D0);
        public static Color Violet => new Color(0xFFEE82EE);
        public static Color Wheat => new Color(0xFFF5DEB3);
        public static Color White => new Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
        public static Color WhiteSmoke => new Color(0xFFF5F5F5);
        public static Color Yellow => new Color(0xFFFFFF00);
        public static Color YellowGreen => new Color(0xFF9ACD32);

        public static readonly Dictionary<string, Color> ByName = new Dictionary<string, Color>
        {
            { "AliceBlue", AliceBlue },
            { "AntiqueWhite", AntiqueWhite },
            { "Aqua", Aqua },
            { "Aquamarine", Aquamarine },
            { "Azure", Azure },
            { "Beige", Beige },
            { "Bisque", Bisque },
            { "Black", Black },
            { "BlanchedAlmond", BlanchedAlmond },
            { "Blue", Blue },
            { "BlueViolet", BlueViolet },
            { "Brown", Brown },
            { "BurlyWood", BurlyWood },
            { "CadetBlue", CadetBlue },
            { "Chartreuse", Chartreuse },
            { "Chocolate", Chocolate },
            { "Coral", Coral },
            { "CornflowerBlue", CornflowerBlue },
            { "Cornsilk", Cornsilk },
            { "Crimson", Crimson },
            { "Cyan", Cyan },
            { "DarkBlue", DarkBlue },
            { "DarkCyan", DarkCyan },
            { "DarkGoldenRod", DarkGoldenRod },
            { "DarkGray", DarkGray },
            { "DarkGrey", DarkGrey },
            { "DarkGreen", DarkGreen },
            { "DarkKhaki", DarkKhaki },
            { "DarkMagenta", DarkMagenta },
            { "DarkOliveGreen", DarkOliveGreen },
            { "DarkOrange", DarkOrange },
            { "DarkOrchid", DarkOrchid },
            { "DarkRed", DarkRed },
            { "DarkSalmon", DarkSalmon },
            { "DarkSeaGreen", DarkSeaGreen },
            { "DarkSlateBlue", DarkSlateBlue },
            { "DarkSlateGray", DarkSlateGray },
            { "DarkSlateGrey", DarkSlateGrey },
            { "DarkTurquoise", DarkTurquoise },
            { "DarkViolet", DarkViolet },
            { "DeepPink", DeepPink },
            { "DeepSkyBlue", DeepSkyBlue },
            { "DimGray", DimGray },
            { "DimGrey", DimGrey },
            { "DodgerBlue", DodgerBlue },
            { "FireBrick", FireBrick },
            { "FloralWhite", FloralWhite },
            { "ForestGreen", ForestGreen },
            { "Fuchsia", Fuchsia },
            { "Gainsboro", Gainsboro },
            { "GhostWhite", GhostWhite },
            { "Gold", Gold },
            { "GoldenRod", GoldenRod },
            { "Gray", Gray },
            { "Grey", Grey },
            { "Green", Green },
            { "GreenYellow", GreenYellow },
            { "HoneyDew", HoneyDew },
            { "HotPink", HotPink },
            { "IndianRed", IndianRed },
            { "Indigo", Indigo },
            { "Ivory", Ivory },
            { "Khaki", Khaki },
            { "Lavender", Lavender },
            { "LavenderBlush", LavenderBlush },
            { "LawnGreen", LawnGreen },
            { "LemonChiffon", LemonChiffon },
            { "LightBlue", LightBlue },
            { "LightCoral", LightCoral },
            { "LightCyan", LightCyan },
            { "LightGoldenRodYellow", LightGoldenRodYellow },
            { "LightGray", LightGray },
            { "LightGrey", LightGrey },
            { "LightGreen", LightGreen },
            { "LightPink", LightPink },
            { "LightSalmon", LightSalmon },
            { "LightSeaGreen", LightSeaGreen },
            { "LightSkyBlue", LightSkyBlue },
            { "LightSlateGray", LightSlateGray },
            { "LightSlateGrey", LightSlateGrey },
            { "LightSteelBlue", LightSteelBlue },
            { "LightYellow", LightYellow },
            { "Lime", Lime },
            { "LimeGreen", LimeGreen },
            { "Linen", Linen },
            { "Magenta", Magenta },
            { "Maroon", Maroon },
            { "MediumAquaMarine", MediumAquaMarine },
            { "MediumBlue", MediumBlue },
            { "MediumOrchid", MediumOrchid },
            { "MediumPurple", MediumPurple },
            { "MediumSeaGreen", MediumSeaGreen },
            { "MediumSlateBlue", MediumSlateBlue },
            { "MediumSpringGreen", MediumSpringGreen },
            { "MediumTurquoise", MediumTurquoise },
            { "MediumVioletRed", MediumVioletRed },
            { "MidnightBlue", MidnightBlue },
            { "MintCream", MintCream },
            { "MistyRose", MistyRose },
            { "Moccasin", Moccasin },
            { "NavajoWhite", NavajoWhite },
            { "Navy", Navy },
            { "OldLace", OldLace },
            { "Olive", Olive },
            { "OliveDrab", OliveDrab },
            { "Orange", Orange },
            { "OrangeRed", OrangeRed },
            { "Orchid", Orchid },
            { "PaleGoldenRod", PaleGoldenRod },
            { "PaleGreen", PaleGreen },
            { "PaleTurquoise", PaleTurquoise },
            { "PaleVioletRed", PaleVioletRed },
            { "PapayaWhip", PapayaWhip },
            { "PeachPuff", PeachPuff },
            { "Peru", Peru },
            { "Pink", Pink },
            { "Plum", Plum },
            { "PowderBlue", PowderBlue },
            { "Purple", Purple },
            { "RebeccaPurple", RebeccaPurple },
            { "Red", Red },
            { "RosyBrown", RosyBrown },
            { "RoyalBlue", RoyalBlue },
            { "SaddleBrown", SaddleBrown },
            { "Salmon", Salmon },
            { "SandyBrown", SandyBrown },
            { "SeaGreen", SeaGreen },
            { "SeaShell", SeaShell },
            { "Sienna", Sienna },
            { "Silver", Silver },
            { "SkyBlue", SkyBlue },
            { "SlateBlue", SlateBlue },
            { "SlateGray", SlateGray },
            { "SlateGrey", SlateGrey },
            { "Snow", Snow },
            { "SpringGreen", SpringGreen },
            { "SteelBlue", SteelBlue },
            { "Tan", Tan },
            { "Teal", Teal },
            { "Thistle", Thistle },
            { "Tomato", Tomato },
            { "Turquoise", Turquoise },
            { "Violet", Violet },
            { "Wheat", Wheat },
            { "White", White },
            { "WhiteSmoke", WhiteSmoke },
            { "Yellow", Yellow },
            { "YellowGreen", YellowGreen }
        };
    }
}
```

And then made a pretty cool page showcasing all colors:

**Colors.razor**

```
@page "/color"
@using Color

<h3>Colors</h3>

<style>
    .square-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .square {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>

<div class="square-container">
    @foreach ((string name, Color color) in Colors.ByName)
    {
    <div class="square" style="@($"background-color: {color.ToCssRgba()}; color: {(color.Luminance > 0.5 ? "black" : "white")}")">
        <p>@name</p>
        <p>@color.ToCssColor()</p>
        <p>@color.ToCssRgba()</p>
        <p>@color.ToCssHsla()</p>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Concerns**:

- It really feels like the `Color` struct should be a struct indeed. I've read about structs vs classes in C# but can't quite get to a conclusion;
- Should I store ARGB into a 64 bit integer for higher precision? It doesn't feels like it is necessary;
- Should all parameters be `double`?
- Shoudl all `uint` parameters by `byte`?
- The use of tuples...? Is there a better way of doing it? It doesn't feel right.

Comment: Tip: refer to [`Color.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Drawing.Primitives/src/System/Drawing/Color.cs) implementation. It can be useful.

Comment: @aepot I based this class mostly on Flutter's [Color](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/lib/ui/painting.dart) which is a much more modern one